# Need Assistance regarding letter count in javardd

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I have to create a letter count program in java spark using JavaRDD just like java Wordcount. But I don't know how will be the split condition is used to separate/calculate the occurrence of each letter in a paragraph. Kindly help me with a working example in java spark thanks in advance. The working code for my javawordcount is given below...

```java
 JavaRDD<String> wordsFromFile = inputFile.flatMap(content -> Arrays.asList(content.split(" ")));

        JavaPairRDD countData = wordsFromFile.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> (int) x + (int) y);

//The above condition is used for word count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For character count we can use content.split("")

```
 JavaRDD<String> wordsFromFile = inputFile.flatMap(content -> Arrays.asList(content.split("")));
```

It will provide the count of each character occurring in the content, If you want only letters ( alphabets ) use filter.